# XQuery Update Facility / Replace node

Tags: xml, xquery

Is a "replace node..." statement anytime equal to an atomic removal of a node (with it's subtree) and an insertion of the content to replace with at the same place?

That is considering we have a DOM-Implementation, in order to support replace-operations is it save to assume the above statement or is something like this also possible (in case of replacing the "foo"-element with a "blabla"-element):

original tree:

- root

  - foo

    - bar
    - baz

modified tree:

- root

  - blabla

    - bar
    - baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may as well use `rename node` to preserve the descendant node structure.

Comment: Hi Christian, yes, I'm aware of rename node which will translate to `setQName(QName)` or `setValue(String)` in our case :-) Just wanted to check that my diff will always detect "replace"-operations and isn't heuristic in this case... (and that my simple implementation of replace is compatible with the XQuery Update Facility recommendation). Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just construct a node `<blabla>` which contains `<foo>`'s contents:

```
replace node /foo with <blabla>{/foo/*}</blabla>
```